# ASP.NET Core: Adding background image to all pages

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to add a background image to all the pages in my web application. However, I've been running into some issues in the past few hours of trying this. I'm using an ASP.NET Core web application with razor pages, and I installed bootstrap using NuGet, which also gave me a site.css file.

In my site.css file, I have the following portion added:

```
#HomepageBody{
    background-image: url("Images/cloud-1581.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

And in my Shared/_Layout.cshtml file I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - CustomerPageTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body id="HomepageBody">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">CD Insights</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Customer/List">Add Assessment</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

In the body portion, I add the ID into it, but when I run the web app, nothing new happens. Any thoughts on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The url of your image is being referenced here in your site.css file: `background-image: url("Images/cloud-1581.jpg");` but the site.css file is located at `~/css/site.css`, so the program is actually looking for the image at the following relative url: `~/css/Images/cloud-1581.jpg` and cannot find it.

Make the reference to the image url absolute with a leading slash, like this: `background-image: url("/Images/cloud-1581.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your Images folder underneath the wwwroot 'folder' in the project.